# Cant enablie HTTPS and HTTP to a clusterIp service behind a Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a Azure Kubernetes service with Nginx-Ingress enabled. This has a web app called OrderService developed in Asp.Net core  which i've deployed and is working.
This service has both HTTP and HTTPS enabled

To access it i have an Ingress controller which looks like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cmb-ingress
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "9"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - orderservice.easetrip.net      
  rules:
  - host: orderservice.easetrip.net      
    http:
      paths:     
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: orderservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

I am not able to access the service via https.

Comment: Can you try making ssl-passthrough to false and retry by adding one more block for 
 443 

host: orderservice.easetrip.net
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: orderservice
            port:
              number: 443

Comment: have you tried kubectl get services to see service address, also kubectl get ingress to get ingress address. Then open them on the browser.

Comment: Arshad please try this once. Remove the annotation for the SSL redirection, this one- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" and  change passthrough to false (This will enable SSL termination) and retry. It should work. Also make sure to check your service manifest if you have added HTTPS protocol and port 443 in there.

Answer (score 0):

To access the order service via HTTPS, you need to add SSL termination so that it can forward the HTTPS traffic to the order service.
Remove the annotation for the SSL redirection,
this one- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"`
and change `passthrough` to `false` because If you’re using SSL passthrough, the backend service should expect the SSL traffic directly without terminating it. So accordingly ensure your backend service (OrderService) is configured to handle SSL traffic if you are keeping `passthrough` as `true`

keeping it to false will enable SSL termination. You can also cross verify the logs to check if this is due to the ssl passthrough.

```
kubectl logs -n <namespace> <nginx-ingress-controller-pod-name>
```

It should work. Also make sure to check your service manifest if you have added HTTPS protocol and port 443 in there.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cmb-ingress
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "9"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - orderservice.easetrip.net      
  rules:
  - host: orderservice.easetrip.net      
    http:
      paths:     
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: orderservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: orderservice
    spec:
      ports:
      - protocol: HTTP
        port: 80
        targetPort: 80
      - protocol: HTTPS
        port: 443
        targetPort: 443
```